# Assign value based on table and ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wish to assign a value in my row which should be based on the country as:

1. Only US: Should be assigned USA
2. only Other countries: Should be
       assigned International
3. US + Other countries: Should be assigned
       Global

So for the below table:

```
    DECLARE @A TABLE
    (
    PolicyID int,
    PolicylocationID int,
    Country VARCHAR(100)
    )
    INSERT INTO @A
    (
    PolicyID,PolicylocationID,Country
    )
    VALUES
    (1,1,'US'),
    (1,2,'US'),
    (1,3,'US'),
    (1,4,'US'),
    (2,1,'NA'),
    (2,2,'PA'),
    (2,3,'CA'),
    (2,4,'ZA'),
    (3,1,'US'),
    (3,2,'NA'),
    --(3,3,'PA'),
    (4,1,'US'),
    --(4,2,'US'),
    (4,3,'US'),
    (5,1,'US'),
    --(5,2,'NA'),
    (5,3,'PA'),
    (6,1,'NA'),
    --(6,2,'PA'),
    (6,3,'CA') 

    Select * into #temp
    from @A
Select * from #temp
```

the output should be:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE
(
PolicyID int,
PolicylocationID int,
Country VARCHAR(100),
CType VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO @A
(
PolicyID,PolicylocationID,Country,CType
)
VALUES
(1,1,'US','US'),
(1,2,'US','US'),
(1,3,'US','US'),
(1,4,'US','US'),
(2,1,'NA','Internationl'),
(2,2,'PA','Internationl'),
(2,3,'CA','Internationl'),
(2,4,'ZA','Internationl'),
(3,1,'US','Global'),
(3,2,'NA','Global'),
--(3,3,'PA','Global'),
(4,1,'US','US'),
--(4,2,'US','US'),
(4,3,'US','US'),
(5,1,'US','Global'),
--(5,2,'NA','Global'),
(5,3,'PA','Global'),
(6,1,'NA','Internationl'),
--(6,2,'PA','Internationl'),
(6,3,'CA','Internationl') 

SElect * into #temp
from @A
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you replace your pictures with text please?

Comment: my bad, edited for convenience

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean - do you actually want to output an INSERT script? Is the grouping based on the ID column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT PolicyID,
                     PolicylocationID,
                     Country,
                     COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'US' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyID) us,
                     COUNT(Country) OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyID) total
              FROM test
            )
SELECT PolicyID,
       PolicylocationID,
       Country,
       CASE WHEN us = total THEN 'US'
            WHEN us = 0     THEN 'International'
            ELSE 'Global'
       END CType 
FROM cte
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=798b71aafb49fe08a2cb438e2786b845)

Comment: perfect, this works!